# Ionic popup and checkbox list

Tags: ionic-framework, popup, checkboxlist

I'm new to ionic framework and i want to know whether i can create a pop up window with a checkbox list in it? For example when a user click on a button a pop up window will come out with a list of things to select.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for $ionicPopup:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

For the `$scope.showPopup` function there is a specified template, this is where you would define the html for a checkbox.

e.g.

```
template: '<ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked.bike">Checkbox Label</ion-checkbox>'
```

You would then have a scope object that is bound to that checkbox.

```
$scope.isChecked = {
     bike: false
}
```

Ionic Checkboxes: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/

Angular Checkbox: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D